# How do I set an Interval only onClick in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

So I am building a Pokemon Idle RPG and I coded in a "buyStarter()" function, so when a player has enough money, they can buy a starter pokemon that will Autoclick for them. For some reason, the interval doesn't begin when the function "buyStarter()" begins.

Below is the  with the called function onClick and beneath is the function that is suppose to set interval if successful.

```js
var starterCost = 250;
var starter = 0;
var autoclick = 0;

function buyStarter() {
  if (count >= starterCost && starter == 0) {
    autoclick = 1;
    starter = 1;
    count = count - starterCost;
    document.getElementById("starterCost").innerHTML = starterCost;
    document.getElementById("starter").innerHTML = starter;
    document.getElementById("autoclick").innerHTML = autoclick;
  } else if (starter == 1) {
    alert("you have already purchased a starter pokemon");
  } else {
    alert("You cannot purchase a starter pokemon");
  }
  setInterval(function(buyStarter) {
    findPokeballs(autoclick);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="image" id="" src="images/pokemon/black-white/1.png" onClick="buyStarter()" value="Send">
```

The process of the feature is, you click and once you earn enough money you can purchase a pokemon to click for you (idle/autoclicker).

Comment: I think the error is probably in the code that's not included here. Note that you have a parameter for your interval function (`function(buyStarter) {...}` that will always be undefined and should be removed. Also, the `setInterval()` should only be called when the starter is successfully bought - otherwise, the player can spam the button to speed up the autocollecting

Comment: @Jotha So would it be better to put this in an if statement? say if (starter == 1) { setInterval... ?

Comment: I would add it into your first if statement, where you also set `autoclick = 1`, `starter = 1` and subtract the cost. That way you make sure that you only set one interval :)

Comment: @Jotha would you be able to give me a practical example? i have tried putting this in the main if statement within the function but it doesn’t seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You mde three mistakes:

1. You added a parameter to the function getting called by `setInterval`, but `setInterval` has no idea what to pass as that parameter
2. You gotta define `count` somewhere, so `var count;` at the top where you're defining other variables
3. You could just do a `setInterval` from the start, and instead have a boolean that switches to true when you want the function to start getting called, this gives you the advantage of more customizability later on (like adding different statements that run/don't run in your `setInterval`.